# "the" before or after "all"

Tags: adjectives, articles, definite-articles

Which one is more correct, if everybody knows that I am talking about all the students in a specific classroom.

> 1. assignments must be done by **all the students**
> 2. assignments must be done by **all students**
> 3. assignments must be done by **the all students**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Assignments must be done by all the students

Every one of the group of students, who are defined either implicitly or by a previous statement, must do the assignments.

As well as being identified by a previous statement, we could go on to define the group; "…by all the students who are doing the advanced course".

> Assignments must be done by all students

Every student must do the assignments.

This could mean the same thing as the first, or not, depending on whether we've a context that defines a particular group, whereas one that gives us a different interpretation of "all students" (generally all taking a particular course, all in a particular school or college, etc. would be obvious from context).

Generally, if we don't have such a defining statement, we'd favour this second. If we do, we'll favour the first.

> *Assignments must be done by the all students

Ungrammatical, and meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

The first two are grammatical, but the third isn’t. Normally, either of the first two will be suitable, but the choice may depend on the context.